# Every struct item gets the last value the user types in

Tags: c

I ask for `d->id` to put it on the list, but if I ask for more than one, all the list items get the last one.

For example, if the `for` has 2 iterations and `novo->prato[0]` is `"M1"` (this is asked to the user) and `novo->prato[1]` is `"M3"`, both positions stay `"M3"`. Why?

Here is the code:

```
typedef struct pedido pedido, *ppedido;
typedef struct prato prato, *pprato;

struct pedido{
    char id[5];
    int prioridade;
    int mesa, n_pratos;
    pprato prato[TAM];
    ppedido prox;
};

struct prato{
    char id[5];
};

int verifica_prato(ppedido p,int j)
{
    FILE *f;
    struct item aux;

    int i=0;

    f = fopen("menu.bin", "rb");
    if(f == NULL){printf("O sistema nao consegue aceder a memoria");return;}

    while((fread(&aux, sizeof(struct item), 1, f)) == 1){
        if((strcmp(p->prato[j]->id, aux.id)) == 0)
            i++;
    }
    fclose(f);

    if(i == 0){
    printf("Prato nao existe no menu.\n");
    return 1;
        }

    if(i > 1)
    return 0;
}


for(i=0;i<novo->n_pratos;i++){
        do{
            printf("ID do prato %d: ", i+1);
            scanf("%s", &d->id);
            novo->prato[i] = d;
            k = verifica_prato(novo,i);

        }while(k != 0);
    }
```

Comment: What is "d"? You should try to provide a minimal (that is, without all the useless struct fields and validation logic), compilable example of your problem.

Comment: It's this. I forgot to put it on the post. Sorry.

pprato d;
 
 d = (struct prato*)malloc(sizeof(prato));

Comment: my bad did not see the typedef

Comment: @missingno You're right, but it's also trivial to see what's wrong just by looking at the code ... given d->id, d must be a pointer to a struct, and the same d is being read into and stored on each iteration. In fact, I was almost sure it was a matter of pointer aliasing just from reading the description.

Comment: @MarcodeBarbosa Rather than remembering to put things in, you should just cut and paste from your code. Clearly that wasn't done, since your for loop is not within any function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the pointer  to structure `d`  when you do `novo->prato[i]  = d` ,
 so each time you make a change to `d` it would be reflected at `novo->prato[i]` since all values in prato array is pointing to the same address i.e. `d`.

I'm not exactly sure what you intend to do but one way could be  to malloc `d` every time in loop before asking the user for input. Remember you also need to look into 'freeing' the memory `prato[i]` eventually.